# Buggy behavior when redirecting from a RowCommand Event?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

One of my columns in the GridView is a CommandField button called "ViewProfile".

The event handler, "MyGridView_RowCommand(...) ", redirects to another page "ViewUserProfile.aspx" when the "ViewProfile" button is clicked.

After clicking "ViewProfile" and being redirected to "UserProfile.aspx", I press the back button.

Now that I'm back on "ViewUsers.aspx", I click any other button which is NOT part of the grid view.

HERE's the buggy part...
The "MyGridView_RowCommand(...)", event fires with an event argument that indicates the "ViewProfile" button was clicked! 
    Yes. When returning the page (after the redirect) clicking any button not inside the GridView somehow 
    causes a RowCommand event to be raised. The odd behavior continues until I refresh the browser.

Anyone know of a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that a cached version was loaded. You could disable caching for this page:

in Page_Load:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

or via adding this meta-tag to your aspx-page:

```
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
```

or via adding the [window.onbeforeunload](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_The_Back_Button_With_Javascript) event to the aspx-page:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
   // This function does nothing.  It won't spawn a confirmation dialog
   // But it will ensure that the page is not cached by the browser.
}
```